# C# - PowerShell - Running multiple long-run PowerShell scripts asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have a .Net solution that takes information from an API Post request (using Web API), runs a local PowerShell script based off of the information, then records the information in a database (using EF6) upon completion.

These PowerShell scripts could take anywhere from a couple seconds to a couple days. Because it would be very inconvenient to wait for the script to make it through a queue, these all need to be run as soon as information is sent through the API.

**My Question:** How can I have multiple local PowerShell instances running at the same time with the ability to parse the results and call methods after execution finishes?

Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: There are some useful examples of asynchronous powershell execution (also for long-running scripts) in this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx

Comment: I'll be sure to check out that blog, and if it proves to be useful I'll post my solution. Thanks!